# excessively print the kernel log bnx2x: [bnx2x_get_regs:987(eth2)]Generating register dump. Might trigger harmless GRC timeouts

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, broadcom, dmesg

My server print the log about "bnx2x: [bnx2x_get_regs:987(eth*)]Generating register dump. Might trigger harmless GRC timeouts" every hour. It has started today and continues print the log every hour. Why does the kernel print this log every hour and how can I found the cause?

note: I didn't run sosreport and ethtool -d

Comment: I found that sosreport created by abrtd. But I do not understand what changed the "abrtd". Normally it's not do create new directory and sosreport only writes the "last_occurrence" file in the /var/spool/abrt/pyhook. How do I stop generated sosreport every time?

Comment: that is the log file:                                                                 
abrt-server[61601]: Saved Python crash dump of pid 61598 to /var/spool/abrt/pyhook-2018-05-19-01:41:46-61598
abrtd: DUP_OF_DIR: /var/spool/abrt/pyhook-2018-04-02-10:41:45-8931
abrt-server[22654]: Saved Python crash dump of pid 22651 to /var/spool/abrt/pyhook-2018-05-19-02:41:46-22651
abrtd: New problem directory /var/spool/abrt/pyhook-2018-05-19-02:41:46-22651, processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dump file was created by a different process and hence deletes all dump files by etc/abrt/abrt.conf.So my Python crash dump file deleted and after recreated by the arbtd at every turn and each time creates sosreport.